# Using XML to serialize an ArrayList of a class that has another ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, serialization, arraylist

I am trying to serialize an ArrayList of a class that has another ArrayList using [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html). Can it be done?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class Model {
    private ArrayList<Student> students;
    private ArrayList<Module> modules;

    //...

    public void saveStudentsXML() throws IOException {
        XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("students.xml")));
        encoder.writeObject(students);
        encoder.close();
    }
    public void loadStudentsXML() throws IOException {
        XMLDecoder decoder=new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("students.xml")));
        students=(ArrayList<Student>)decoder.readObject();
        decoder.close();
    }
    //this works fine

    public void saveModulesXML() throws IOException {
        XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("modules.xml")));
        encoder.writeObject(modules);
        encoder.close();
    }
    public void loadModulesXML() throws IOException {
        XMLDecoder decoder=new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("modules.xml")));
        modules=(ArrayList<Module>)decoder.readObject();
        decoder.close();
    }
    //this does not

}
```

The `Module` class has another ArrayList of the `Student` class (each module has a list of enrolled students),

```
private ArrayList<Student> enrolledStudents;
```

and when I reviewed the XML, there didn't seem to be any information about the enrolledStudents ArrayList.

Edit: I have created setters and getters for all instance variables *except* the enrolledStudents ArrayList. As far as I know, you can't create a setter method for an ArrayList, right? Is there another way I can get XMLEncoder to encode this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that you can in fact create setters for ArrayLists, it was just something I had never needed to do before, and stupidly assumed it couldn't be done.

I tried this after realising I hadn't created a getter or setter for the ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<Student> getEnrolledStudents() {
    return enrolledStudents;
}
public void setEnrolledStudents(ArrayList<Student> enrolledStudents) {
    this.enrolledStudents = enrolledStudents;
}
```

It was all I needed to add to the Module class, and it worked fine after that.